# Returning a GeoJSON object in java

Tags: java, json, geojson

I am new to GeoJSON and im currently running into an issue that I just don't know how to do it.

Here is a snippet of what my FeatureCollection looks like

```
        FeatureCollection fc = new FeatureCollection();
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < platforms.size(); i ++) {
            Feature feature = new Feature();
            Point geometry = new Point();
            Dto dto = platforms.get(i);
            Position position = new Position(dto.getLat(), dto.getLon());

            fc.addFeature(feature);
            geometry.setCoordinates(position);
            feature.setGeometry(geometry);
            feature.setProperties(properties);

            properties.put("name", dto.getName());
            properties.put("msl", dto.getMsl());
            properties.put("id", dto.getId());
 
        }
        return fc.toString();
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
{
                "type":"FeatureCollection"
                features":[ 
                {
                            "type":"Feature"
                            "geometry": {
                                "type":"Point"
                                "coordinates":[
                                   -120.200000,
                                     10.100000 
                                     ] 
                                  }, 
                                  "properties": {
                                     "name": "1"
                                     "height": "100.00"
                                     "id": "null"
                                  }
                               }
                {
                            "type":"Feature"
                            "geometry": {
                                "type":"Point"
                                "coordinates\":[
                                  -130.200000,
                                     20.100000
                                    ] \n "
                                  }, \n "
                                  "properties": { "
                                     "name": "2"
                                     "height": "100.00"
                                     "id": "null"
                                  } 
                              } 
                            ] 
                 }
```

As far as I can tell, through debugging, the correct information is being placed into the feature but whenever I return the featureCollection I get this:

```
mil.nga.sf.geojson.FeatureCollection@366ac49b
```

I don't know much about geojson but it seems like I'm incorrectly returning the FeatureCollection and its printing out its name or whatever.

Simply put, how do I print the contents of a FeatureCollection?

EDIT:
This is the output that I get after implementing gson.

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "feature": {
        "geometry": {
          "x": 10.1,
          "y": -120.2,
          "z": null,
          "m": null,
          "geometryType": "POINT",
          "hasZ": false,
          "hasM": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "msl": 100.0,
          "name": "1",
          "id": null
        }
      },
      "id": null,
      "bbox": null,
      "foreignMembers": {}
    },
    {
      "feature": {
        "geometry": {
          "x": 20.1,
          "y": -130.2,
          "z": null,
          "m": null,
          "geometryType": "POINT",
          "hasZ": false,
          "hasM": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "msl": 100.0,
          "name": "2",
          "id": null
        }
      },
      "id": null,
      "bbox": null,
      "foreignMembers": {}
    }
  ],
  "bbox": null,
  "foreignMembers": {}
```

I am unsure what to do moving forward to get this to mirror my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `fc.toString();`, which will hit the default Object.toString() method. This will dump some classname+address/id-like String, depending on th JVM used.

Instead of calling toString(), you should use a JSON library like google gson, and add
a few lines to the bottom of your code:

```
    final GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    gb.setPrettyPrinting();
    gb.serializeNulls();
    // gb.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation(); // maybe use for more control

    final Gson gson = gb.create();
    final String jsonText = gson.toJson(fc);
    return jsonText;
```

Also consider writing a utility class that does this for you with default settings that you choose:

```
public class MyJsonUtil {
    static public String toJSON(final Object pObject) {
        final GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
        gb.setPrettyPrinting();
        gb.serializeNulls();
        // gb.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation(); // maybe use for more control

        final Gson gson = gb.create();
        final String jsonText = gson.toJson(pObject);
        return jsonText;
    }
}
```

and then at the end of your code you simply call `return MyJsonUtil.toJSON(fc)`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get an output with your recommendation. There is an issue though, the format hardly matches that of what I want my Geojson output to look like.
For instance the first line that should be "type":"FeatureCollection" is missing from the output. Is this a formatting thing with gson?

Comment: Added the output in the original post as an edit.

Comment: Where you write 'I want my output to look like this, that JSON code has invalid formatting; there is a comma missing after `"type":"FeatureCollection"`. Or brackets. So if "type" and "features" are supposed to be on the same level / have the same parent, you could 1) write another class that extends your FeatureCollection and adds that one property, 2) write another class that has the variables type and features copied from the FC,3) you can add that variable to your current FeatureCollection class, and 4) you can write custom serializers (check google) and 5) you can tweak the string manually